# Script Delayed - Waiting For Quota

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

As of a few days ago I periodically get messages like `Script delayed (13.0 min) waiting for quota` while testing some of my apps.

Looking through [the quotas](https://script.google.com/dashboard) it doesn't seem like I would be going over any of the limits as most flat out don't apply to this app and the rest are orders of magnitude over the amount of requests I'm making.

Can I safely ignore these messages?  I can't find anything else helpful in the google cloud logs or in my 10 minutes of poking around to try and find my current usage.  For the few services that do report the quota I am far below the limit (to my knowledge only MailApp has such a function - correct me if there are more).

Comment: Is someone else using your account?